# Uncaught TypeError: Can not read properties of undefined (reading 0)

Tags: echarts

we have a chart of type custom in which visualMap is used. for some reason on hover of visualMap echart is throwing following console error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSxk0.png)

What could be probable reason for the error?

We tried checking if any issue with data but seems like normal.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If you provide a mininal reproducable example in the [echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple) it might be possible to help.